# Given base and leg lengths of Trapezoid calculate median length and length of leg from midpoint

Tags: geometry

I have an acute trapezoid with the short base of 60cm (top), long base of 135cm (bottom), left leg of 70cm and right leg of 50cm. So AB = 60, BC= 50, CD=135, DA=70. I can easily calculate the median base length (average of both bases) = 97.5. Points PQ represent the median line (97.5) across the middle of the trapezoid. I have also been able to calculate the height of the trapezoid by using Pythagorus equation and solving for height by subtracting the the equation for one triangle from the other i.e.

eq1) (75-x)^2 + h^2 = 70^2 
eq2) x^2 + h2 = 50^2

So.. (75-x)^2 - x^2 = 70^2 - 50^2
x = 21.5
Solving for h (back to Pythagorus) I get h = 45.14

But now, how do I solve for the length of PA (median line point on left side to base point A)?

Answer (score 0):

If you know $cosB$,  you can use the Law of Cosines on triangle ABP to find the length of AP. angleB is the supplement of angleC, so $cosB$=-$cosC$.Let point E lie on CD 60cm to the right of point D   You can find $cosC$ by considering the triangle EBC with EB=70, BC= 50 and EC=135-60. Use Law of Cosines on this triangle to find  $cosC$.